# Operate (i.e. search) on non-root aggregates in DDDS

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregation

Question about using Aggregates (not AR) in Domain Driven Design.

Using the familiar: Order (aggregate root [AR]) and OrderLine (aggregate member [AM]) works for an example.  If one assumes that the Orders are persisted, then how does one, properly from a DDD perspective, operate on the aggregate members?

For instance, can I search (find operation) for all the OrderLines of a given item?  What is the correct way to do that?  If I return those as Value Objects, that just seems wrong, in reality they are persisted Domain Objects.  Furthermore, I might need to be able to get the Order from one of them.  Yet, if I return them (from the Repository layer) as Entity objects, then I seem to have violated the Aggregate Root canonical rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to my question.  If I now follow correctly, it's completely okay to know about an entity below the aggregate root.  However, one can not store/view/reference an ID to it.  But you CAN reference the AR Id.

Thus, I can have say: OrderRepository.findOrderLines(withProductId) method that returns a list of OrderLine objects less their Id, but having the Order Id (AR ID) on those objects is fine.

Please comment if this is off-base.

Comment: If you're playing by the rules of DDD.  It would be good to have a method like `FindOrdersContainingProduct(productId)` in your repository, that would return a collection of `Orders`, not `OrderLines`.  You would not be able to retrieve `OrderLines` from your repository, what you would do is return the complete `Order`.